# jQuery Change radio button on select box change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not very good with jQuery and I am having trouble getting this right. I need to change the radio button selected if I select a certain value in a different select box.

```html
    <div class="radio-inline" id="sourceDiv" role="group">
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns1" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="CN"><label for="sourceBtns1">CHINA</label>
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns2" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="ID" ><label for="sourceBtns2">INDONESIA</label>
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns3" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="TH" ><label for="sourceBtns3">THAILAND</label>
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns4" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="US"><label for="sourceBtns4">UNITED STATES</label>
</div>
```

```html
<div id="priceSelect">
<select name="priceSelect" id="priceSelect" class="form-control">
     <option value="FTLW">Domestic Full Truck Load</option>
     <option value="PTLW">Domestic Partial Truck Load</option>
     <option value="FTL" selected>International</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the radio button to select #sourceBtns4 when the "FTLW" option is selected in the select box.

This is the function that I am using. I do not get an error, but I cannot get the function to work. I am not sure what the problem is. I have tried several different things, but none of them work.

Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'FTLW' ){
   $('#sourceBtns4').prop("checked", true);
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two elements with the same `id`. Your `div` and your `select` both had an `id` of `priceSelect`. It's only the `select` that you care about.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
  if($(this).val() == 'FTLW' ){
   $('#sourceBtns4').prop("checked", true);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select name="priceSelect" id="priceSelect" class="form-control">
     <option value="FTLW">Domestic Full Truck Load</option>
     <option value="PTLW">Domestic Partial Truck Load</option>
     <option value="FTL" selected>International</option>
    </select>
</div>
   <div class="radio-inline" id="sourceDiv" role="group">
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns1" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="CN"><label for="sourceBtns1">CHINA</label>
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns2" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="ID" ><label for="sourceBtns2">INDONESIA</label>
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns3" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="TH" ><label for="sourceBtns3">THAILAND</label>
 <input type="radio" id="sourceBtns4" name="sourceBtn" class="btn btn-lg" value="US"><label for="sourceBtns4">UNITED STATES</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I feel real dumb. You are exactly right. It works fine now.

Comment: Hey @Scott, you are probably more knowledgeable about this than I am, why shouldn't you use .on('change', ...) instead of .change()? Or is that just choice? I know .on() is for dynamic event handling, but is there any detriment to always specifying handlers with on()?

Comment: @rob The jQuery documentation (https://api.jquery.com/change/) tells us that `change()` " is a shortcut for `.on( "change", handler)`."